# Cleanly recreate 10.3 enterprise geodatabase in Oracle 12c

Tags: arcgis-10.3, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase

Recently I created an enterprise geodatabase on a virgin Oracle 12c instance, using ArcCatalog. I eventually dropped the SDE schema and attempted to recreate the enterprise geodatabase. Now I get the following error:

`Failed to insert a value to the geodatabase system table.GDB_ItemTypes`

According to the log, the underlying Oracle exception is:

`ORA-00001: unique constraint (SDE.R6_SDE_ROWID_UK) violated`

I have a feeling that SDE is leaving behind bits and pieces elsewhere in my Oracle instance. Is there a reliable way to cleanly remove all traces? Or is something else going on?

**Edit:** I am also now seeing a lot of messages like this in `sdedc_Oracle.log`:

```
[Mon Oct 24 13:10:49 2016] [50049085] [XPLWS02] db_execute_sql OCI Execute Error (4043).
[Mon Oct 24 13:10:49 2016] [50049085] [XPLWS02] db_execute_sql OCI Execute Error (942).
[Mon Oct 24 13:10:49 2016] [50049085] [XPLWS02] db_execute_sql OCI Execute Error (2289).
```

Each of the OCI error codes maps to one of the Oracle "not found" error codes (e.g., https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00942.php).

Comment: I will comment that uninstalling and reinstalling Oracle 12c resolved the issue. :-/

Comment: You can corrupt your Oracle instance if you DROP the SDE user before you drop all the tables using the SDE.ST_GEOMETRY type.  At that point, uninstall/reinstall is your only option.

Comment: I'd like to reopen this question because it CAN be reproduced and there IS  a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the resolution (per Vince) is... drop all tables using the SDE.ST_GEOMETRY type before dropping the SDE user. If you forget to do that the database will become corrupt and you must uninstall and reinstall Oracle. (Having just learned a thing or two about pluggable databases, I would wager that in the world of Oracle 12c one could simply create a new PBD.)